# Fixing Laravel URL structure issue hosting migration

Tags: php, laravel

I have the project running but relative paths are relative to the domain and not the domain's `/` folder as I specified in the settings file in `app/config/app.php`.

In aparatado URL so I have:

```
domain.com/folder
```

However in my project when I go to a relative URL e.g. `/users` leads me to 
`domain.com/user` and not `domain.com/folder/user`.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: What is a `aparatado URL`?

Answer (score 0):

What you probably have is a problem on your webserver virtual host configuration:

This is **an example** of configuration to use your application in folders:

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
        ServerName myServer
        ServerAlias myServer
        DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>


Alias /folder "/var/www/folder"
<Directory /var/www/folder>
  Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then you just access them using

```
http://domain.com/folder
```

Or 
    http://domain.com/folder/user

It will not get out from your `/folder`.

Also, you might need to configure your `public/.htaccess` accordingly:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    ...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/index.php/?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```